# First-child selector in CSS .less file

Tags: css, less

I have a list of links in a footer and want add a left border to each one of them apart from the first, I'm trying the following but it removes all the left borders:

```
ul.footerLinks {
margin:0 auto;
li{
    display: inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    color:#eee;
    padding:4px 14px;
    border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    &:hover {
        color:#fff;
        border-top:1px solid #fff;
    }
    &:first-child {
        border-left:none;
    }
}
```

}

I also tried adding the border to the right and using `:last-child` but same result, all borders disappeared.

Anything obviously wrong?

Comment: So is the border on the `li` or the `a`...because all `a` tags would probably be the first-child of an `li`

Comment: Code works for me - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/CnhcF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As paulie_d said, it does work, I had the `<a href="#"></a>` outside the `<li>`, once I moved it inside as below it works ok.

```
<nav role='navigation'>
   <ul class="footerLinks">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like below . Even i am new, just trying to help.

```
li{
        display: inline-block;
        zoom:1;
        *display:inline;
        color:#eee;
        padding:4px 14px;
        border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);

        &:hover {
            color:#fff;
            border-top:1px solid #fff;
        }
       &:not(:first-child) {
        border-left:1px solid #fff;
    }
    }
```

***Or Simply***

```
    li{
            display: inline-block;
            zoom:1;
            *display:inline;
            color:#eee;
            padding:4px 14px;
            border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);

            &:hover {
                color:#fff;
                border-top:1px solid #fff;
            }

        }

li:not(:first-child) {
     border-left:1px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you replace `li` with `ul` (or `ol`, depends on the tag you have), it removes the border of the first `li`.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should have been a comment.